# What are the 8 Consciousness in Chinese Buddhism

Tags: theravada, pali-canon, mahayana, chinese-buddhism, chinese-canon

The answeres to the following question: [Is the Ocean Samadhi a metaphor or an actual meditation?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/13686/is-the-ocean-samadhi-a-metaphor-or-an-actual-meditation) implply there are 8 types of conciousness in Chinese Buddhism. What are these? How did they originate? Is this there a common text with Theravada which is cited deriving or rationalising this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_Consciousnesses) page:

> All surviving schools of buddhist thought accept – "in common" – the existence of the first six primary consciousnesses (Sanskrit: vijñāna, Tibetan: རྣམ་ཤེས་, Wylie: rnam-shes).[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_Consciousnesses) The internally coherent Yogācāra school associated with Maitreya, Asaṅga, and Vasubandhu, however, uniquely – or "uncommonly" – also posits the existence of two additional primary consciousnesses, kliṣṭamanas and ālayavijñāna, in order to explain the workings of karma.[2] The first six of these primary consciousnesses comprise the five sensory faculties together with mental consciousness, which is counted as the sixth.